# Change XML structure

Tags: replace, sed, grep, xmlstarlet

Hi I need make some text manipulation of this part of xml.
Deleting some tags is no problem. I need before that rename car ID to CAR_ID and move inside TRIP tags.

ie: MLStarlet Toolkit ?

xmlstarlet somevariable

Original

```
  <car>
    <id>155028827</id>
    <trip>
      <id>1</id>
      <date>1.1.1970</date>
    </trip>
    <trip>
      <id>2</id>
      <date>1.1.1970</date>
    </trip>
  </car>
```

Expection result

```
<trip>
  <car_id>155028827</id>
  <id>1</id>
  <date>1.1.1970</date>
</trip>
<trip>
  <car_id>155028827</id>
  <id>2</id>
  <date>1.1.1970</date>
</trip>
```

Comment: what do you already try  and what is the failing part or unwnated behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say

```
xmlstarlet ed -i '/car/trip/descendant::node()[1]' -t elem -n car_id -u '/car/trip/car_id' -x 'ancestor::node()["car"]/id/text()' filename.xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -c '/car/trip'
```

This falls into two parts:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
   -i '/car/trip/descendant::node()[1]' -t elem -n car_id \
   -u '/car/trip/car_id' -x 'ancestor::node()["car"]/id/text()' \
   filename.xml
```

and

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '/car/trip'
```

The first is an `xmlstarlet ed` command, which means that XML goes in, is edited, and edited XML goes out. The edits are

```
   -i '/car/trip/descendant::node()[1]' -t elem -n car_id
```

which inserts a `car_id` before the first descendant of every `/car/trip` node, and

```
   -u '/car/trip/car_id' -x 'ancestor::node()["car"]/id/text()'
```

which sets the value of all `/car/trip/car_id` nodes to the text inside the `id` subnode of their `car` ancestor node. This alone produces

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<car>
  <id>155028827</id>
  <trip>
    <car_id>1550288271</car_id>
    <id>1</id>
    <date>1.1.1970</date>
  </trip>
  <trip>
    <car_id>1550288272</car_id>
    <id>2</id>
    <date>1.1.1970</date>
  </trip>
</car>
```

which is then piped through

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '/car/trip'
```

This selects (and prints) the `/car/trip` nodes of this XML data, producing

```
<trip>
    <car_id>1550288271</car_id>
    <id>1</id>
    <date>1.1.1970</date>
  </trip><trip>
    <car_id>1550288272</car_id>
    <id>2</id>
    <date>1.1.1970</date>
  </trip>
```

You could, if the formatting annoys you, use

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '/car/trip | /car/text()'
```

to preserve the whitespaces between the tags (and get more readably formatted output); with this change, the output is

```
  <trip>
    <car_id>1550288271</car_id>
    <id>1</id>
    <date>1.1.1970</date>
  </trip>
  <trip>
    <car_id>1550288272</car_id>
    <id>2</id>
    <date>1.1.1970</date>
  </trip>
```

...with two more blank lines at the top; they're the newlines before and after the `/car/id` node. Unfortunately, the output data is no longer valid XML, so we can't just pipe it through an XML pretty-printer (which is what I'd really like to do). Since my suspicion is that this will be embedded in further XML (so that it can be properly parsed), in the event that formatting is important, my suggestion is to embed this first and pipe the whole XML through a pretty-printer afterwards.

Comment: You are the best. thx a lot, Im not a programmer and "descendant::node()[1]" sounds like music from Mars for me :) . Non xml standart is no problem, I'll preparing xml for insert to mysql. Thx again.

Comment: Those filters are [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) expressions; `descendant` is an [Xpath axis](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp). XPath is a very convenient tool when handling XML (and not very difficult to learn), so I encourage you to read up on it.

Comment: You can use `--root` or `-R` (as in `xmlstarlet sel -R -t ...`) to get the output wrapped into a single node.